# NextJS detect lnaguage without using URL

Tags: next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

How we can change user language without using the url and headers detection!

The issue with the URL is that the user when get back to the website, the language will be returned to the default language `(e.g. en)` not the language that the he has selected last time he visited the website `(e.g. ar)`.

So I want to store the language at `localStorage` on my app's settings page . then Next.js app get the language from the `localStorage`.

I know nextjs didn't do that how I should change the code or is there another lib that can to that?

How we can achieve that?

Thanks